# OSX Finder read-only Windows IIS WebDAV

Tags: macos, webdav

I have a WebDAV set up on my Windows 2008 R2 server using IIS. When I try to mount it on OSX using finder I have read-only access. What do I need to change to get full access?

I have added my account to the WebDAV rules, I have rw permissions on the disk and enabled simple_lock.

**Update:**

- I can mount the location on Windows machines

Comment: Have you verified that it's not a Finder issue, e.g. by connecting using Transmit or Cyberduck?

Comment: Whoa! Weird combination of technologies there...

Comment: @Daniel, I can't seem to mount it on Transmit.. I am running the WebDAV on a port different from 80, but I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: Can you mount it on any system other than the one server?

Comment: I can mount it on my Windows 7 machine without any problems.

Comment: Do you have Active Directory or any other Windows-only networking stuff running that might interfere? Are you able to connect to the WebDAV volume from *any* Windows machine, or only machines properly set up for your specific networking environment?

Comment: No active directory. Mounting works from other Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

OS X Finder requires a WebDAV server that supports WebDAV Class 2 locking. The windows WebDAV only supports WebDAV Class 1.

Use another product such as BarracudaDrive that supports WebDAV Class 2.
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/

Comment: I thought IIS 7.5 had this supported. I have been able to connect with write access with enabling anonymous verification enabled.